# How to check if any of multiple elements are in a List in a convenient way?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to write the following condition:

```
if(javaList.contains("aaa")||javaList.contains("abc")||javaList.contains("abc")) {
    //do something
}
```

How can I do it in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on java 8 and higher, you can use the following code :

```
if (javaList.stream().anyMatch(l -> l.matches("aaa|xyz|abc")))
```

You can use `.matches()` and pass in the *Strings* separated by the *OR* symbol. The `.matches()` takes in a *String*, represented as a *regex*.

Comment: This was direct. But even answer by https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989452/8799862  works .

Answer (score 9):

It's usually more efficient to run `contains` on a `Set` than on a `List`. Therefore I suggest you create a `Set` of the elements you want to test, and then stream over the `List` to see if any of its elements matches:

How about:

```
if (javaList.stream().anyMatch(e -> Set.of("aaa","abc","def").contains(e)))
```

Comment: Better one. I guess `Arrays.asList("aaa","abc","def")` should be used instead of `Set`?

Comment: @JohnHumanyun why do you think that? Set.contains is usually more efficient than List.contains. Of course, when the Set/List contains few elements, it doesn't matter.

Comment: may be i'm wrong , but it throws Set.of(String,String,String ) is undefined error

Comment: @JohnHumanyun `Set.of` is used from Java9+ you can use a simple Set instead, just look in google

Comment: @YCF_L This is what I was missing . +1

Comment: When written that way (`.anyMatch(e -> Set.of("aaa","abc","def").contains(e))`), it will repeat the `Set` creation for every list element (until the JVM manages to optimize this). In contrast, just specifying `.anyMatch(Set.of("aaa","abc","def")::contains)` is enough to ensure that only one `Set` is created and reused for every element evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Set and check the intersection.

```
Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(listOfThings);
intersection.retainAll(Set.of("aaa","abc","def"));
```

Check if size > 0 and then you can also see what things it contained, it that is of interest.